# sql-injection finding when using a prepared-statement in java

Tags: java, prepared-statement, sql-injection

I am getting an sql injection and tried using a prepared statement to solve it but not sure if using it correctly. Here is an excerpt of my code if anyone can tell me what I am doing wrong.

```
public synchronized boolean updateCisReqId(long newValue, long reqId) throws DAOException {
boolean success = false;
PreparedStatement pStmt = null;
String sql = null;
Connection conn = null;
try {
  sql = "UPDATE " + reqTable + " SET CIS_REQ_ID = ?" + " WHERE REQ_ID = ?";
  //        conn = PPSDbMgr.getUniqueInstance().getConnection();
  conn = CIFDBManager.getUniqueInstance().getConnection();

  if (conn != null) {
    pStmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
    if (pStmt != null) {
      pStmt.setLong(1, newValue);
      pStmt.setLong(2, reqId);
      /*System.out.println (PPSDbMgr.getUniqueInstance().
                             getConnection().nativeSQL(sql));*/
      if (pStmt.executeUpdate() == 1) {
        success = true;
        conn.commit();
      }
    }
  }
```

when checking in my code I get a sql injection security finding on: pStmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);

Comment: Where does `reqTable ` come from?

Comment: /**
 * Data Access Object - Responsible for accessing the request db table.
 */
public class RequestDAO {
  public final long NO_VALUE = -1;
  public final String reqTable = "REQ";
  private static RequestDAO uniqueInstance;
  private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(RequestDAO.class.getName());

Comment: it's a db table

Comment: @raptor, yes it is the db table but why is it a variable and how is that initialized? That will explain whether you have potential sql injection or not.

Comment: @raptor you should escape reqTable to remove all dangerous character. Image than somewill but to regTable string with value = 'sameTable set 1=1;drop table .....;'

Comment: @raptor Where do you get the "sql injection security finding"? And what is the complete full message from that finding?